# Error reading dataset in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have problem in reading a dataset

My code :

```
require(igraph)
g <- graph(c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 
               4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 
               8, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 9))
```

Error :

```
Error in graph(c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7,  : 
  At structure_generators.c:84 : Invalid (negative) vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be vertex of name `0`

```
yourgraph <- c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 
               4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 
               8, 6, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 9)

g <- graph(yourgraph + 1)
```

Comment: Probably a hangover from when the `igraph` package used 0 indexes because that's what the underlying C code used. There was an `igraph0` package that kept the 0-indexing while people changed to using 1-indexing but that's gone now.

Comment: I wanted to maintain the `igraph0` package, but the CRAN maintainers removed it....